# How to fully annotate (blame) source with copy detection?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, blame

I know that I can enable annotations in Eclipse using `(right mouse click on a line)` – `Team` – `Show Annotations`. However, that does not use copy detection or move detection machinery of `git`. With `git gui blame` I can select "Do Full Copy Detection" which does `git blame -C -C -C -M` behind the scenes. How to do the same thing with Eclipse/EGit?

(Note that I'm using a Eclipse version where [Eclipse JGit bug 374382 - annotations misses revisions after merge commit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374382) has already been fixed so my problem is really about copies and moved code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a bug in on this website. Looks like this is related to me.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439344